# WordPress RSS Feed is not functions in a PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin called WP- RSS feed. As it so happens, acording to their website you can use an RSS feed directly inside of your PHP template. When I place the following code into the template, it does not fire but instead I get an error that says, "Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /nas/wp/www/staging/sfhr/wp-includes/SimplePie/Content/Type/Sniffer.php on line 97"

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(RSSImport(5,"http://www.indystar.com/apps/pbcs.dll/section?Category=SPORTS0107&template=rss"));
 ?>
```

The code for line 97 is the following:

```
if (($pos = strpos($this->file->headers['content-type'], ';')) !== false)
        {
            $official = substr($this->file->headers['content-type'], 0, $pos);
        }
        else
        {
            $official = $this->file->headers['content-type'];
        }
```

Any ideas why I get these erros?

Comment: Is this still unsolved?

Comment: What happened is that there was an extra space after the ending of each photo document I was using. When I removed the extra space it seemed to clear up the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, it's good to hear you found the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the plugin **RSS-Import**

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/

then according to the documentation, you can add this into your template files:

```
<?php RSSImport(10, 'http://bueltge.de/feed/'); ?>
```

If you want to use `do_shortcode()` then you could try this:

```
<?php 
  echo do_shortcode('[RSSImport display="5" feedurl="http://bueltge.de/feed/"]');
?>
```

You can also fetch RSS feeds without plugins with the Wordpress function `fetch_feed()`:

```
<?php $feed = fetch_feed( $uri ); ?>
```

This function is using the SimplePie package and caches the feeds automatically. You can read more about it here in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed